# Let $f\colon H \to L(H,X)$ strongly continuous ($X,H$ Hilbert spaces). Is the adjoint function $f^*\colon H \to L(X,H)$ strongly continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $X,H$  be Hilbert spaces and let $f\colon H \to L(H,X)$, where $L(H,X)$ is the space of linear bounded operators. In this case it is natural to define the adjoint function $f^*\colon H \to L(X,H)(=L(X^*,H^*))$ by
$$f^* (x)=[f(x)]^* \quad \forall x \in H,$$
where $*$ denotes the adjoint of the operator $f(x) \in L(H,X).$

Clearly if $f$ is continuous in the operator topology, we have that $f^*$ is continuous in the operator topology, i.e. as $|x- x_0|_H\to 0$
$$\|f^*(x)-f^*(x_0)\|_{L(X,H)}=\|f(x)-f(x_0)\|_{L(H,X)} \to 0.$$

However, assume that $f$ is strongly continuous, i.e.
$$\lim_{|x-x_0|_H\to 0}|f(x)\eta-f(x_0)\eta|_X=0 \quad \forall \eta \in H. $$
Is then $f^*$ strongly continuous in this case? I.e. we should have
$$\lim_{|x-x_0|_H\to 0}|f^*(x)y-f^*(x_0)y|_X=0 \quad \forall y \in X$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $H = X = l^2(\mathbb{N})$ and $v$ be the adjoint of the unilateral shift. We define a function $g: \mathbb{R} \to L(H)$ first by,

$$g(t) = \begin{cases}
0 &, \, \mathrm{if} \, t \leq 0\\
\frac{\frac{1}{n}-t}{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}}v^{n+1}+\frac{t-\frac{1}{n+1}}{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}}v^n &, \, \mathrm{if} \, \frac{1}{n+1} \leq t < \frac{1}{n}, \, n \in \mathbb{N}_+\\
v &, \, \mathrm{if} \, t \geq 1
\end{cases}$$

Since $v^n \to 0$ strongly as $n \to \infty$, it is easy to verify that $g$ is strongly continuous. Now simply let $f(h) = g(\mathrm{Re}\langle e_1, h \rangle)$. Clearly $f$ is still strongly continuous. But $f^\ast$ is not strongly continuous. Indeed, $\frac{1}{n}e_1 \to 0$, but $f^\ast(\frac{1}{n}e_1) = g(\frac{1}{n})^\ast = (v^n)^\ast$, which does not converge strongly (to $f^\ast(0) = 0$ or any other operator).

Comment: are other examples of this kind available on some book or do you know if there is a book which addresses a similar topic?

Comment: @carlos85 I don’t remember any book specifically addressing this question of yours, mostly because you’re defining the function on $H$, which is quite unusual. But really, this is nothing more than saying taking adjoints is not continuous in the strong operator topology, which is a quite standard fact.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. But do you know any condition under which taking adjoints preserves continuity in the strong operator topology or do you know any reference where something like this can be found?

Comment: @carlos85 Taking adjoints is strongly continuous when restricted to normal operators. This can be found, for example, as Theorem 4.3.1 of Murphy’s “$C^\ast$-algebras and operator theory”. It is also continuous when restricted to uniformly norm bounded sets in a tracial von Neumann algebra because then the strong operator topology coincides with the 2-norm and taking adjoints is isometric under the 2-norm, see Proposition 2.6.4 of https://www.math.ucla.edu/~popa/Books/IIunV15.pdf